# How to retrieve all rows from up to down in MySQL after sum to some specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum, window-functions

Let's say I have these type of data in a database table. How can I perform a query like when I pass some value it should sum from up to down rows and select all the rows which are required to sum up the value.

1. When I pass value 11 it should sum from up to down rows and sum rows with id 1 2 3 i.e (3+2+7) as 11 falls in third row range and select all rows that equals or have greater) the value.
2. Let's say if I pass 20 value it should sum row 1 2 3 4 as 20 falls in (3+2+7+10) 4th column and select all 4 rows.

```
ID, TABLE_COLUMN
1,2
2,3
3,7
4,10
5,11
6,15
```

I have tried doing this and it works but it seems so so slow. When I query in 20K data table, it takes about 20 seconds and more to retrieve 10 rows of data.

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.TABLE_COLUMN
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t2.TABLE_COLUMN), 0)
       FROM yourTable t2
       WHERE t2.ID < t1.ID) < 20;
```

MySQL version is 5.7.12. (Amazon AWS MySQL Aurora; that means I cannot upgrade the version of MySQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can just do a window sum and filter by that:

```
select id, table_column
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(table_column) over(order by id) wsm
    from mytable t
) t
where wsm >= 20 and wsm - table_column < 20
order by id
```

In earlier versions, your query seems like a reasonable option to me. For performance, you want an index on `(id, table_column)`.

Alternatively, you could try and emulate the window sum with a user variable:

```
select id, table_column
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        @wsm := @wsm + table_colum wsm
    from (select * from mytable order by id) t
    cross join (select @wsm := 0) v
) t
where wsm >= 20 and wsm - table_column < 20
order by id
```

Comment: GMB i would love to do that but actually i m running my production db in amazon aws RDS mysql Aurora . and it doesn't provide 8.0 version as of now . thanks :)

Comment: @imDevD: I updated my answer with a discussion about earlier versions.

Comment: Hey @GMB , i am using second option with window sum .now what i want is to skip some value . like lets say in the above column When I skip 3 and pass value 11 it should sum from up to down rows and sum rows with id  2 3 4 i.e (3+7+10) as first row is skipped and 2nd is included as 2 is remaining there. please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Replace 20 with your required value):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable y WHERE id <=

( SELECT MIN(id) FROM (
SELECT t1.id, t1.table_column,SUM(t2.table_column)running_total
FROM yourtable   t1, yourtable   t2 
WHERE t2.id <= t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.table_column
) as i

WHERE i.running_total >= 20

)ORDER by y.id
```

Comment: cant run in phpmyadmin says unrecognized statement type. (near WITH) i am using MySQL version is 5.7.12.

Comment: SAM i m not getting as expected , like when i pass 1 it should have select first row and when i pass 3 it should select first and second row . DEMO => https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62b85a248a6f87433d832b3d16f42ed4

Comment: SAM it seems to work but this is too so so slow when i tested it. i have more then 100K+ datas in my table.. any other ideas on this ? thanks :)

Comment: Post the TEXT of EXPLAIN (your query); so we can see what your Optimizer is doing with the query, please.  With this post, we will know how many rows were examined and indexes considered and used for the query.

Comment: @imDevD there are few things by considering which i believe data retrieval can be faster e.g. 1) Add new column 'RUNNING_TOTAL' and maintain it while adding new record 2) column 'ID' and 'RUNNING_TOTAL' must be indexed (if not before) another way, creating new table 'CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE AS SELECT QUERY... (above inner query which contains Group By clause) with indexing on ID and RUNNING_TOTAL and then fetch data from NEWTABLE

Comment: @WilsonHauck SAM  TEXT of EXPLAIN  (my query); =>
1 PRIMARY y 
    NULL
 range PRIMARY PRIMARY 8 
    NULL
 1 100.00 Using where 
2 SUBQUERY <derived3> 
    NULL
 ALL 
    NULL
 
    NULL
 
    NULL
 
    NULL
 83324 33.33 Using where 
3 DERIVED t1 
    NULL
 ALL PRIMARY 
    NULL
 
    NULL
 
    NULL
 500 100.00 Using temporary 
3 DERIVED t2 
    NULL
 ALL PRIMARY 
    NULL
 
    NULL
 
    NULL
 500 33.33 Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)

Comment: SAM column 'ID' is my primary key

Comment: @imDevD Please post the query that was used to run EXPLAIN. Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck query is 
SELECT * FROM yourtable y WHERE id <=

( SELECT MIN(id) FROM (
SELECT t1.id, t1.table_column,SUM(t2.table_column)running_total
FROM yourtable   t1, yourtable   t2 
WHERE t2.id <= t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.table_column
) as i

WHERE i.running_total >= 20

)ORDER by y.id

Comment: @imDevD If you could avoid the use of less than by making equivalent BETWEEN selection you will likely save time. The EXPLAIN on the second line selected 33 percent of the 83,324 rows from the derived table.  Could this number be reduced?  Would the WHERE t2.id <= t1.id GROUP BY t1.id,t1.table_column perform better with WHERE t1.id <= t2.id GROUP BY t1.id,t1.table_column so the driving table is same as your GROUP BY?